# Adjusting HTML Table Cell Width using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have HTML table as shown below. It has seven columns. I am adjusting the table cell width using jQuery. The total percentage is 100 in the jQuery. However, the table is not taking the complete space; there is some unused space. How to correct this?

http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/eFS5J/3/

[image]

```
 $(document).ready(function () {


        $('#gridDiv').css('width', '630px');


        //Set width of table cells
        var numberOfColumns = 7;
        $('.resultGridTable th, .resultGridTable td').each(function (i) {


            $(this).css('background-color', (['Purple', 'Orange', 'Purple', 'Orange', 'Purple', 'Orange', 'Purple'][i % 7]));

            if (i % numberOfColumns == 0) {
                $(this).css('width', '15%');
            }

            if (i % numberOfColumns == 1) {
                $(this).css('width', '15%');
            }

            if (i % numberOfColumns == 2) {
                $(this).css('width', '15%');
            }

            if (i % numberOfColumns == 3) {
                $(this).css('width', '15%');
            }
            if (i % numberOfColumns == 4) {
                $(this).css('width', '10%');
            }
            if (i % numberOfColumns == 5) {
                $(this).css('width', '15%');
            }

            if (i % numberOfColumns == 6) {
                $(this).css('width', '15%');
            }


        }
 );


    }
);
```

Comment: is there a reason why you want to do that in jquery and not css?

Comment: The problem is probably because the table itself has to be width:100%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following attribute to your table element.

```
width="100%"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
<table class="resultGridTable" cellspacing="0" id="detailContentPlaceholder_grdTaxAssociates" style="border-collapse: collapse; width:100%;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Only set width as 100% by using inline css in below place

```
<table class="resultGridTable" cellspacing="0" id="detailContentPlaceholder_grdTaxAssociates"
                    style="border-collapse: collapse;width:100%;">
```

[See demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/eFS5J/8/)